# whereNotIn removes all values in the laravel model table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, delete-row

```
MyMode::whereNotIn('id', $someCollection->pluck('id')->toArray())->delete();
```

removes all values from the table. But I think it shoudt remove only items which are not present in `$someCollection`. 
How to remove items which are not in `$someCollection->pluck('id')->toArray()`?

Answer (score 1):

It should work without a problem. You should verify first what you have in `$someCollection->pluck('id')->toArray()` to make sure it doesn't return all/none rows from `MyMode` model.

Comment: thanks. I sent two requests, and in the second request $someCollection was empty

Comment: @Alex So this was for sure the reason. If collection was empty `whereNotIn('id', [])` caused choosing all rows from table, so all rows were deleted.